# Check if string is between two letters

Tags: c#, string

I am working on decoding VIN numbers into useful information and for the country they give a range of double letters (EG: SA-SM is Great Britain). How do I check to see that SG is between SA and SM? I was thinking about hex but this can't be converted to hex because of it going past E.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (String.Compare("SG","SA") > 0 && String.Compare("SG","SM") < 0)
{  // SG between SA and SM
}
```

Ignore case

```
if (String.Compare("SG","SA",true) > 0 && String.Compare("SG","SM",true) < 0)
{  // SG between SA and SM
}
```

You can also use one of CurrentCulture, CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, InvariantCulture, InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, Ordinal, OrdinalIgnoreCase ([msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx))

```
if (String.Compare("SG","SA",CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > 0 && String.Compare("SG","SM",CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) < 0)
{  // SG between SA and SM
}
```

Comment: String also has a `CompareOrdinal` method.  This works well if your strings include both letters and numbers (which a vin might).  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

```
value[0] == 'S' && value[1] >= 'A' && value[1] <= 'M'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using a number, hex is not the only base out there: what about base-26?

```
var str = "SK";
var base26 = 26*(str[0]-'A')+(str[1]-'A');
```

There is nothing wrong with comparing strings lexicographically, as long as both strings are of the same length.

Comment: This is fun if there is a lowercase `a` :D

Comment: @Hogan where would a lowercase `'a'` come from, if I just initialized the string to `"SK"`? :):):) Jokes aside, I think you raised a good point: the string needs to be converted to upper case, and checked to contain only letters before converting to base-26.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly my point -- roll-your-own is fun but `String.Compare` gives much more power having been already written.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way :

```
string test= "SASGSM";
if(test.IndexOf("SG") > -1) {

 //your action

}
```

Comment: That's not what he meant by "between"

Comment: Yes, he's talking about "in the range between," not literally characters inside of a string.