# LINQ - BETWEEN "a" AND "e"

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Generic List of Students. I want to filter the student name starts `between "a" and "e"` with the help of LINQ.

```
Students = Students.Where(s => s.Name.Substring(0, 1) == "a" 
                            && s.Name.Substring(0, 1) == "e").ToList();
```

Please help me to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737683/check-if-string-is-between-two-letters

Comment: @Jesuraja, So, student name that start with `b` or `c` should be get from your query. right?

Comment: Its better you consider case-insensitivity for somparison..The names most likely starts with Capital Letters.

Comment: @AbhilashPA Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @Jesuraja, I prefer you to use `regular expression`. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Untested by this might work:

```
Students = Students.Where(s => s.Name.Substring(0, 1) >= "a" 
                        && s.Name.Substring(0, 1) <= "e").ToList();
```

Alternatively

```
Students = Students.Where(s => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
                               .contains(s.Name[0]).ToList();
```

Comment: does matter for "A" vs "a", you could do `s.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()` or `s.Name[0].ToLower()`

Comment: I was actually thinking about sql, but the question was 'just' linq, so indeed it should matter in code. Just tested it in mssql and it regards for collation, which is good to know. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4):

Range defined by less/greater, not by just ==:

```
 Students = Students.Where(s => s.Name.Substring(0, 1) >= "a" 
                        && s.Name.Substring(0, 1) <= "e").ToList();
```

You also may want to lowercase or compare to both cases.

Answer (score 4):

There's multiple ways to do it. Here's two:

You can still go with your original code, but convert your equality check for a **range** check:

```
Students = Students.Where(s => s.Name[0] >= 'a' && s.Name[0] <= 'e');
```

Alternatively, you can also directly use the [ASCII values](http://www.ascii-code.com/):

```
Students = Students.Where(s => s.Name[0] >= 97 && s.Name[0] <= 101);
```

Please note that we're using `Name[0]` here instead of `Substring` so we can get the `char`/`int` value of the letter, instead of a `string`.

---

The other way, that can be used if the chars are not adjacent, would be to create a list and check if the first letter is contained in that list:

```
string[] chars = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
Students = Students.Where(s => chars.Contains(s.Name.Substring(0, 1)));
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do so by adding a method that casts the chars to ints whos [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) can then be compared:

```
private static bool StartsWithRange(string value, char first, char last)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
  {
    return false;
  }

  if (first > last)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("'{0}' shouldn't come after '{1}'.", first, last), nameof(last));
  }

  int intValue = value.ToLower()[0];
  return intValue >= first && intValue <= last;
}
```

Usage:

```
Students.Where(s => StartsWithRange(s, 'a', 'e')).ToList();
```

I tested different cases and it seems to work:

```
Assert.IsFalse(StartsWithRange("abcd", 'd', 'e'));
Assert.IsTrue(StartsWithRange("dcd", 'd', 'e'));
Assert.IsTrue(StartsWithRange("Dcd", 'd', 'e'));
Assert.IsTrue(StartsWithRange("ebcd", 'd', 'e'));
Assert.IsTrue(StartsWithRange("Ebcd", 'd', 'e'));
Assert.IsFalse(StartsWithRange("fbcd", 'd', 'e'));
Assert.IsFalse(StartsWithRange("Fbcd", 'd', 'e'));
Assert.IsFalse(StartsWithRange(string.Empty, 'd', 'e'));
```

Please note the `ToLower`-call, this is required if not all `value`s are in the same case.

This works if the values are all in a row, if they are just "random" letters, then I would use the array-approach as described above.

Comment: I really like the usage of a unit testing framework to list the test cases.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer you to use regular expression.

```
students = students.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, @"^[a-e].*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) == true).ToList();
```

Here you can see that I have used the regular expression `@"^[a-e].*"` to indicates that we have to mach student names those have names start with `a,b,c,d,e`. So you can easily modify your filter to get students.

*Note :* Please include the namespace `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to use regular expression in your project.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this with the info you give.

```
var s = new [] {"a","b","c","d","e"};
Students = Students.Where(s => s.Contains(s.Name.Substring(0, 1))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understood correct.

```
Students = Students.Where(s => {
   char c = s.Name[0];
   return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'e') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'E') ;
}).ToList();
```

I also included the capital letters.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest way to do this without using additional string manipulation methods is:

```
var filter = Students.Where(s => s!= null && s [0] >= 'a' && s[0] <= 'e').ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.CompareOrdinal` method.

```
Students = Students.Where(s => 
string.CompareOrdinal(s.Name.Substring(0, 1), "a") >= 0 && string.CompareOrdinal(s.Name.Substring(0, 1), "e") <= 0)
.ToList();
```

It will include "a" and "e". You can use uppercase conversion before comparing also for case insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider implementing a Between extension method and use it.

Code Sample:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        var names = new string[] { "andy", "lisa", "zoro", "billy" };

        var result = FilterBetween(names, 'a', 'e');
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> FilterBetween(IEnumerable<string> names, char start, char end)
    {
        return names.
            Where(name => name.
                First().
                Between(start, end));
    }



public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool Between<T>(this T actual, T lower, T upper) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return actual.CompareTo(lower) >= 0 && actual.CompareTo(upper) <= 0;
    }
}
```